# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(\sqrt[t]{t}-1)^{n}t}{2^{t}}dt=\frac{\operatorname{Ei}(-\ln2)}{\ln2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Let $$T(x)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(\sqrt[t]{t}-1)^{x}t}{2^{t}}dt$$
Then show that;

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nT(n)}{n}=\frac{\operatorname{Ei}\left(-\ln2\right)}{\ln2}$$

Where $\operatorname{Ei}(x
)=-\int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt$, the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: Your own attempts?.. (Did you try the obvious $\sum\int\mapsto\int\sum$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nT(n)}{n}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_1^\infty\frac{(\sqrt[t]{t}-1)^nt}{2^t}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_1^\infty\frac{t}{2^t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-\sqrt[t]{t})^n}{n}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_1^\infty-\frac{t}{2^t}\ln{(\sqrt[t]{t})}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln{(t)}}{2^t}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\frac1{\ln{(2)}}\int_{\ln{(2)}}^\infty\frac{\ln{(u/\ln{(2)})}}{e^u}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\frac1{\ln{(2)}}\int_{\ln{(2)}}^\infty(e^{-u}\ln{(u)}-\ln{(\ln{(2)})}e^{-u})\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\frac1{\ln{(2)}}\left[\text{Ei}(-u)-e^{-u}\ln{(u)}+\ln{(\ln{(2)})}e^{-u}\right]_{\ln{(2)}}^\infty\\
&=-\frac1{\ln{(2)}}\left[(0-0+0)-\left(\text{Ei}(-\ln{(2)})-\frac{\ln{(\ln{(2)})}}{2}+\frac{\ln{(\ln{(2)})}}{2}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{\text{Ei}(-\ln{(2)})}{\ln{(2)}}\\
\end{align}